# OpenGL + SDL_TTF: texture index recycling

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl-ttf

I am currently in the process of migrating a bunch of applications from SDL2 rendering (internally using OpenGL) to "pure" OpenGL rendering. During this work I have figured out how to upload textures to the GPU and learned that every texture has an index.

To render text I use the SDL_TTF functions that allow you to, basically, upload a texture to the GPU depicting some text. Most applications I am migrating aren't text heavy but I noticed a possible problem with them.

Imagine an application that accepts user text input and puts in on the screen: each keystroke would generate a new texture with all the text entered (any other previous texture related to the same functionality would be deleted). So, to write "Hello" we would get five textures: "H", "He", "Hel", "Hell" and finally "Hello". As said, every "previous" texture (in this case from "H" to "Hell") would be deleted and only the memory for "Hello" would remain.

Still, in text heavy applications (for example, using this method to put the score of a game, doing it badly enough that you generate a new texture for each frame) lots of textures would be uploaded and deleted and the texture index would keep on growing.

My main question here is: will OpenGL recycle those indexes or will it just run out of numbers and crash?.

PS: I am aware of the possibility of packing all the TTF characters into an atlas and just get the letters I need. I wouldn't like looking into that now unless my current approach is dangerous (this atlas thing sort of feels like old bitmap fonts).

PS2: I am also aware that changing textures constantly isn't exactly performant (GPU wise) but these applications aren't graphically challenging and have good performance in older systems.

Comment: If it concerns you, why not just replace texture data without recreating texture id/name? I.e. `glTexImage` again, or allocate big texture and replace parts of its data later.

Comment: Yes, yes, that's exactly what I am planning on doing in the future :). See, all texts that may change (for example, the aforementioned score marker in a game or hint boxes) are encapsulated in classes that manage the deletion of their resources (these usually have long lifespans, not a lot of indexes would be consumed). I could very well extend them to "replace" the current texture but I was unsure about some legacy code I have lying around. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenGL objects are referred to by what the OpenGL specification calls "names" (other often used terms in programming are "handle" or "id"/"identifier"). When a new name is first bound (with `glBind…`) a corresponding OpenGL object (texture, buffer, etc.) is created; some OpenGL functions create objects and return the name to it (`glCreate…`). After a (valid) name is deleted (with `glDelete…`) the corresponding OpenGL object will be deallocated once the last internal reference to it gets released. Names may be validly reused (by OpenGL) after deleting them, thereafter referring to a *different* object.

---

Don't reinvent the wheel. Text rendering with OpenGL is ridiculously convoluted and there does not (yet¹) exist the one perfect method. There are however several libraries that address the texture generation and resource management problems. Do yourself a favour and use one of those. In your case freetype-gl would be the best option (IMHO): https://github.com/rougier/freetype-gl

---

1: I'm currently working on a new shader based glyph rasterizer that addresses most of the known problems, but it's not done yet.

Comment: Datenwolf, thanks for the post but it doesn't really answer the question that was posted about index recycling. Right now I am not interested in using new libraries as much as I am in knowing a bit about how it all works. Still, thanks, I will keep Rougier in mind when it all goes south :).

Comment: @TheMarlboroMan: If you properly `glDeleteTextures` and unbind unused texture names (will happen eventually) texture names are going to be recycled. Texture names are not required to be either incremental or without gaps.

Comment: I am doing glDeleteTextures in the destructor of the texture class itself so that part is clear. To be honest, I don't even know that there's a "texture name" feature in OpenGL so I guess I am safe. Would you mind updating your answer with the recycling information so I can solve this question?.

Comment: Accepted answer. Seems the "name" is what I am referring to as "index" so everything is under control now. Once a texture has been created and the index obtained, would the same glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, myindex);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, w, h, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixel_data); code chunk suffice to replace a texture?. I am assuming it does but can't check now.

Comment: @TheMarlboroMan: Yes, calling glTexImage2D will fully replace the texture associated with the name. The previously associated texture object will be deallocated as soon as all *internal* references to it are released (a object might still be associated with operations queued up in the pipeline), but this happens behind the scenes. Any resource leaks are bugs in the OpenGL implementation.

Comment: that's great news for me. I'm gonna give a new implementation a try and check everything remains in order. I truly appreciate the support: OpenGL has a lot of corners for those new to it but good advice makes navigating them much more bearable. Thanks again.